# 対応する括弧を削除するには？

Tags: emacs, elisp

たとえば、次のような elisp があります。

```
(hoge fuga
      foo bar
      piyo
      moo
      aaa)
```

これを、次のような形に編集したいです。

```
hoge fuga
      foo bar
      piyo
      moo
      aaa
```

何かというと、対応する括弧のペアを削除する、がやりたいことです。
これを実現する編集コマンドはありますか？

(raise-sexp が近いのですが、これをやると、たとえば `hoge` だけが残る形になってしまいます。。)

Comment: `delete-pair` では？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delete-pair` がほしかったものでした。